# How can I get the time of a crawled tweet ? Or crawl tweets for a specific time period

Tags: r, twitter

I'm trying to crawl tweets with the following code:

```
library("twitteR")
library("ROAuth")

consumer_key <- '###'
consumer_secret <- '###'
access_token <- '###'
access_token_secret <- '###'

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

search_string <- URLencode("#stackoverflow")
no_of_tweets <- 2
tweets <- searchTwitter(search_string, n = no_of_tweets, lang="fr")
tweets
```

It works well but I get results in the following format:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Account: content of the tweet which contains #stackoverflow"

[[2]]
[1] "Another_account: content of that other tweet which contains #stackoverflow"
```

That's nice but I'd also like to retrieve the time at which the tweet was sent. Is this possible?

Alternatively, I'd be okay if I could send a time period in my API call. I know it's possible for a date, with this, for instance :

```
search_string <- URLencode("#stackoverflow since:2017-01-04 until:2017-01-05")
```

But I can't find how to be more precise than a day. This doesn't work :

```
search_string <- URLencode("#stackoverflow since:2017-01-04T10:00:00 until:2017-01-04T10:30:00")
```

Any idea on how to achieve either of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the function `twListToDF` to convert the object into a dataframe with details.

```
tweets <- searchTwitter("#stackoverflow", n = 2, lang="fr")
tweetsDF <- twListToDF(tweets)
```

Now, to get the time of the tweet have a look at `created` column which will give you the time the tweet was sent.

To get tweets withing a specific duration we can use the `since` and `until` parameters in `searchTwitter` function

For example -

```
searchTwitter("#stackoverflow",since = "2016-01-10" until = "2016-01-12")
```

This will give you tweets between these dates.

`since` and `until` take input only the format `YYYY-MM-DD`

If we need to subset the tweets based on time we can use the same `created` column like

```
tweetsDF[tweetsDF$created > as.POSIXct("2017-01-04 10:00:00") & 
                            tweetsDF$created > as.POSIXct("2017-01-04 10:30:00"),]
```

Comment: `twListToDF()` is very nice, thank you. However if `searchTwitter("#stackoverflow",since = "2016-01-10" until = "2016-01-12")` works, `searchTwitter("#stackoverflow",since = "2016-01-10T10:00:00" until = "2016-01-12T14:00:00")` doesn't. Would you know a way to pass hours/minutes/seconds to the `since` and `until` fields ? Thanks

Comment: Well of course I can do that, but that's just requesting all the tweets and then filtering on my time interval, I was expecting a way to call the API for my time interval, without retrieving any tweets out of the interval...

Comment: @fmalaussena Ohh..in that case I am not aware if that can be done.

Comment: I'm beginning to think it can't be done :(. Anyway, thank you for your very useful answer nonetheless !